# Is there any up-to-date alternative software for Computer Model for Feasibility Analysis and Reporting (COMFAR)?

Tags: linux, open-source, modeling, analytics

I need a feasibility study for my startup and I heard that COMFAR (Computer Model for Feasibility Analysis and Reporting) is suitable. COMFAR facilitates short and long-term analysis of financial and economic consequences for industrial and non-industrial projects.

COMFAR seems outdated, and would prefer something suitable for Linux. Can anybody recommend an alternative? Linux-based, free and open-source is preferred, but other models and alternative implementations might be suitable.

Comment: It's a software request, but I didn't know where to ask. Should I remove this?

Comment: I believe this is on topic for Software Recommendations Stack Exchange with the edits, but will need to be retagged and possibly improved with additional details to fit the site. Please see their help center for additional details to ensure you get the most suitable answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[COMFAR seems to be a tool developed by UNIDO (United Nations Industrial Development Organization).](https://www.unido.org/resources-publications-publications-type/comfar-software)

According to this UNIDO document, [Independent Evaluation -
UNIDO Computer Model for Feasibility Analysis and Reporting (COMFAR) Activities](https://www.unido.org/sites/default/files/2010-12/Comfar_0.PDF):

> For many users the main alternative to COMFAR is to use a self-made
> excel model. This can be a more flexible tool for financial modelling.

If you are on Linux, you can use Calc, the spreadsheet app in LibreOffice.